Number of indecomposable modules over representation-finite hereditary algebras
Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra over a field $K$ that is hereditary and of finite representation type.
It is well known that they are classified by Dynkin diagrams.
For algebraically closed fields (or more generally quiver algebras) the number of indecomposable $A$-modules is given by the positive roots.

Question: Is there a general formula for the number of indecomposable modules (in terms of n, the number of simple modules and possible the field $K$) for a given representation-finite hereditary $K$-algebra $A$. Does this depend on the field $K$ or just on the Dynkin type?

This should be well known but I didnt find a good answer in the standard textbooks. I mainly search a good reference to cite.

What depends on the field is which Dynkin diagrams can occur, not the classification of indecomposables. For example, over an algebraically closed field only the simply laced ones occur (so A, D, E; not B, C, F, G).

@DaveBenson That (the algebraically closed field case) I know. And most textbooks give formulas for the number of indecomposables for type A,D, E but I havent found formulas for types B,C,F,G. Do you know a reference?

The bijection between indecomposables and positive roots is a theorem of Gabriel from the early seventies. See for example my Representations and Cohomology I, Chapter 4. You do need the algebra to be split over its radical, for it to be Morita equivalent to the path algebra of a Dynkin diagram, but this is automatic if the field is perfect.

If you just want to know the number of positive roots, look at the table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#Properties_of_the_irreducible_root_systems and divide the second column by two.

@DaveBenson Thanks, and what happens for general (possibly non-perfect) fields? Also Im confused $C$ (the complex numbers) as a $R$-algebra ($R$ is the real numbers) is hereditary and $R$ is perfect, but $C$  is not Morita equivalent to a path algebra over $R$, or?

Please read Chapter 4! Over a non-algebraically closed field, what you have to do is assign a division ring to each vertex and a bimodule to each edge. The non-perfect case is discussed at the end of Section 4.1.

@DaveBenson Ok, I will read it. Thanks again.
